# Trouble sending the Jwt in the request header

Tags: retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to get a response from a simple protected Endpoint in the back end.

I've tested the Endpoint in Postman. I set up GET request with the KEY: Authorization and a VALUE: bearer eyxhsls...(this is the Jwt)
and the response gives me Status: 200 OK and the requested String. So everything works fine in the back end.

Now I want to replicate this process on the Client-side using Retrofit. Based on some research I using an OkHttpClient.Builder to insert the Jwt(String) into the header.

I try different things like simply inserting the Jwt(String) into header value:

```
Request.Builder newRequest = request.newBuilder().header("Authorization", bearerToken);
```

This returns a 401 status

I have also added the  "Bearer " to the VALUE, just like I did in Postman, but the caller referred me to the onFailure method with the Message:

```
use jsonreader.setlenient(true) to accept malformed json at line 1 column 1
```

So I have added a GsonBuilder with setLeniet to the addConverterFactory. the caller again referred me to the onFailure method, but with the Message:

```
JSON document was not fully consumed.
```

Plz, let me know if anyone has a better idea, or understands what is going on. But stuck now for a number of days now.

```
 public CoffeeController() {

        okhttpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
             @NonNull
             @Override
             public okhttp3.Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
                 Request request = chain.request();

                 bearerToken = "Bearer " +LoginController.getToken();
                 bearerToken = LoginController.getToken();

                 Request.Builder newRequest = request.newBuilder().header("Authorization", bearerToken);

                 return chain.proceed(newRequest.build());
             }
         });

        gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/")
                .client(okhttpBuilder.build())
                //.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }

    public static void CoffeeRead(Context context, TextView ResponseView) {
        try {
            CoffeeRepo repo = retrofit.create(CoffeeRepo.class);
            Call<String> call = repo.Read();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    message = "Read Coffee: " +"\nToken: " +bearerToken +"\nResponse: " + response.code();
                    ResponseView.setText(message);
                    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                    message = "Failed to read coffee: \n" + t.getMessage();
                    ResponseView.setText(message);
                    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            message = "Caught Exception: \n" + e.getMessage();
            ResponseView.setText(message);
            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }




public interface CoffeeRepo {
    @Headers({
            "Cache-Control: max-age=3600",
            "User-Agent: Android"
    })
    @GET("coffee")
    Call<String> Read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After I've added a logger, I found out the response was 200. After some research I found out I needed different ConverterFactory, instead of:

```
.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
```

I used

```
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
```